# toString in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, tostring

The toString method was generated in eclipse as follows :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("Person [");
if (firstName != null)
    builder.append("firstName=").append(firstName).append(", ");
if (lastName != null)
    builder.append("lastName=").append(lastName).
if (title != null)
    builder.append("title=").append(title).append(", ");
if (car != null)
    builder.append("car=").append(car).append(", ");
    builder.append("]");
```

Why didn't they use more short form e.g.

```
builder.append("firstName=" + firstName + ", ");
```

Is it to save time with `String` creation?

How do I change template to this format ?

```
${object.className} [${member.name()}=${member.value}, ${otherMembers}]
```

Comment: Not only is it faster, but it is more 'proper'. Technically it's also more proper to do something like: `System.out.print("age=");System.out.println(age);`

Comment: @Legend Why is it more proper?

Comment: It uses the more official methods. There are methods for Objects and all the primitive types, so use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first form is ever so slightly faster - in the other forms additional `StringBuilder` are created within the byte code. In general this does not matter much unless string creation is performed in a tight loop.

As for the second question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
builder.append("firstName=" + firstName + ", ");
```

is strictly less efficient than the form Eclipse is using, since it creates an intermediate `String` that then gets immediately discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you can change the template in the Eclipse Preferences: Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates.